# How to set camera under fragments of action bar tab?

Tags: android

I have developed an application in which i have used action bar with three tabs.Each tab is having its own fragment and under one fragment I want to start camera in one fragment.I don't know how to do it.Please suggest me some way so that i can implement that in my application.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation and training? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: My suggestion is to read and try to follow the official documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) and then if you have a specific problem, come back again with a less generic question.